# Thickness for \sout{} (strikethrough) command from ulem package

Tags: ulem, strikeout

I am using `\sout` from the `ulem` package together with `beamer` to strike through some text:

```
\documentclass[mathserif]{beamer}
\usepackage{ulem}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  Next meetings: 
  \begin{itemize}
    \item \sout{22.01.2016} (cancelled) 
    \item 28.01.2016
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

However, I would like to have the line a bit thicker because it's so thin that people might miss it. How is that possible?

Answer (score 17):

The `ulem` source states that:

> To draw a line through text instead of under it (strike out) do under-line with negative depth.

So, the thickness of the strike is the same as that of the underline. From the `ulem` package documentation:

> The thickness of the underline rule is given by the command macro
>   `\ULthickness`; use `\renewcommand` (not the usual `\setlength`) to change
>   it.

So, writing:

```
\documentclass[mathserif]{beamer}
\usepackage{ulem}
\newcommand{\soutthick}[1]{%
    \renewcommand{\ULthickness}{2.4pt}%
       \sout{#1}%
    \renewcommand{\ULthickness}{.4pt}% Resetting to ulem default
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  Next meetings: 
  \begin{itemize}
    \item \soutthick{22.01.2016} (cancelled)
    \item \sout{22.01.2016}
    \item 28.01.2016
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

you will get:

[image]

Comment: Hm, so there's no easy way to adjust the width for `\sout` without changing the thickness for underlines?

Comment: @fuenfundachtzig Sorry for the late response. Apparently no! I updated my answer to make a new command with different line thickness.

Answer (score 7):

You can exploit the fact that `\sout` opens a group, so any assignment to `\ULthickness` will be local.

```
\documentclass[mathserif]{beamer}
\usepackage{ulem,xpatch}

\xpatchcmd{\sout}
  {\bgroup}
  {\bgroup\def\ULthickness{2pt}}
  {}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  Next meetings:
  \begin{itemize}
    \item \sout{22.01.2016} (cancelled)
    \item \uline{28.01.2016}
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: i don't know why, but this doesn't work for me.  the other answer does work.

Comment: @dbliss I tried it again on a fresh file and it works.

Comment: @dbliss It's silly to downvote a working solution; are you using exactly the same example? If you're integrating it in another document there are several other factors that can influence the result. No information, no clue for helping you.

Comment: To overwrite `\sout`'s `\bgroup` but without using the `xpatch` package or `\xpatchcmd`, use `\def` to redefine the meaning of `\sout` like this:  `\def\sout{\leavevmode \bgroup\def\ULthickness{2pt}\ULdepth=-.55ex \ULset}`.  This modifies line 257 of ulem.sty, dated 2019-11-18.